# How to run pip install when both python 2.x and 3.x installed on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables

I am learning Python, the first book I used required python 2.x, the next book is based on 3.x and have installed both on my window 10 laptop, however  when I run pip install on the command line it only works for python 2.x (the one I installed first) what modifications do I need to type to run pip install on python 3.x on a Windows 10 operating system.

Comment: use  virtual enviornment : http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: Use `py -2 -m pip` and `py -3 -m pip` to add packages to the system installations.